# Where to start writing a simple java app for a mobile platform?

Tags: java

//Backstory

i have a LG Rumor Touch phone, and it comes with a couple social media apps that are just awful to use, and restrictive as far as features.

//Question

Ive worked with people before making iphone apps who would write basically like a "wrapper" that would just invoke a browser window inside the app to load a site where the app actually ran, im looking to do something similar but using java, but am wanting some advice as to where to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/), the Android version looks like a good fit for what you are trying to accomplish, since you mentioned Java in the tag.

I dont know enough about the LG Touch OS development... so I apologize if off track

Here is an [Android Quick Start](http://wiki.phonegap.com/phonegap-android-eclipse-quickstart)